# Is there a list of 'if' switches anywhere?

Tags: bash, if-statement, switch-statement, shell-exec

Is there a list of all the `if` switches for use in Bash scripting? Sometimes I see someone using it and I wonder what the switch they're using actually does.

An example is the `-z` in this one. I know how to use it, but I don't know where it was derived from.

```
if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    echo -e "Error: this script requires the BASH shell!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Any references, guides, posts, answers would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

Comment: `[` is a short name for the `test` command. Try `man test`.

Comment: @Barmar you mean `help test`.  `man test` is the documentation for `/bin/test`, and it supports different options from the `test` builtin

Comment: `-z` is is an option to `[` or `test`; it has nothing (directly) to do with `if`.

Comment: Tangentially, to better understand the syntax of the actual `if` statement (which this isn't actually about, as several of the answers here point out), see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371221/checking-the-success-of-a-command-in-a-bash-if-statement

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Look at the Bash man page (`man bash`).  The options are specified in the `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` section:

```
CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS
       Conditional expressions are used by the [[  compound  command  and  the
       test  and [ builtin commands to test file attributes and perform string
       and arithmetic comparisons.  Expressions are formed from the  following
       unary  or  binary  primaries.   If any file argument to one of the pri-
       maries is of the form /dev/fd/n, then file descriptor n is checked.  If
       the  file  argument  to  one  of  the  primaries  is one of /dev/stdin,
       /dev/stdout, or /dev/stderr, file descriptor 0, 1, or 2,  respectively,
       is checked.

       Unless otherwise specified, primaries that operate on files follow sym-
       bolic links and operate on the target of the link, rather than the link
       itself.

       -a file
              True if file exists.
       ... more options ...
```

It is also explained in the help:

```
$ help [
[: [ arg... ]
    This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last
    argument must be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.
```

Comment: Online manual: [Bash Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html)

Answer (score 17):

Yes. These are called [***conditional expressions***](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) and these are used by the `[[` [*compound command*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Compound-Commands) and the `test` and `[` [*builtin commands*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins) (`[` is simply a synonym for `test`).

Read section [6.4 Bash Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) of the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), which contains a list of all these switches and their usage.

Comment: Single page: [6.4 Bash Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html)

Answer (score 9):

The single square brackets (`[ ... ]`) is an synonym of the `test` command. If you look at the [man page for test](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/test1.html), you will see almost all (Bash might have a few extra not mentioned here) of the various *if switches* as you called them. All in one easy-to-find place.

If you use double square brackets (`[[ ... ]]`), you are using an extended Bash set of tests. These mainly have to do with regular expression matching, and glob matching (and extended glob matching if you have that set too). For that, you'll have to read that Bash man page.

You called them *if switches*, but that's not really correct. These are *tests* and really have nothing to do with the `if` command.

The `if` command merely executes the command you give it, and then if that command returns an exit code of `0`, will run the `if` portion of the `if` statement. Otherwise, it will run the `else` portion (if that's present).

Let's look at this:

```
rm foo.test.txt   # Hope this wasn't an important file
if ls foo.test.txt

> then
> echo "This file exists"
> else
> echo "I can't find it anywhere.."
> fi
ls: foo.test.txt: No such file or directory
I can't find it anywhere..
```

The `if` statement runs the `ls foo.test.txt` command and the `ls` command returns a non-zero because the file does not exist. This causes the `if` statement to execute the `else` clause.

Let's try that again...

```
touch foo.test.txt   # Now this file exists.
if ls foo.test.txt   # Same "if/else" statement as above

> then
> echo "This file exists"
> else
> echo "I can't find it anywhere.."
> fi
foo.test.txt
This file exists
```

Here, the `ls` command returned a `0` exit status (since the file exists and the file exists and can be stat'ed by the `ls` command.

Normally, you shouldn't use the `ls` command to test for a file. I merely used it here to show that the `if` statement executes the command, then executed the `if` or `else` clause depending upon the exit status of that command. If you want to test whether or not a file exists, you should use the `test -e` command instead of `ls` command:

```
if test -e foo.test.txt  # The same as above, but using "test" instead of "ls"
then
    echo "This file exists"
else
    echo "I can't find it anywhere..."
fi
```

If the file exists, `test -e` will return an exit status of `0`. Otherwise, it will return a non-zero exit status.

If you do this:

```
ls -i /bin/test /bin/[

10958 /bin/[    10958 /bin/test
```

That `10958` is the *inode*. Files with the same *inode* are two different names for the same file. Thus `[` and `test` command are soft linked<sup>1</sup>. This means you can use `[` instead of `test`:

```
if [ -e foo.test.txt ]
then
    echo "This file exists"
else
    echo "I can't find it anywhere.."
fi
```

Does it look familiar?

---

<sup>1.</sup> In Bash, the `test` and `[` are builtin, so when you run these commands in BASH, it isn't running `/bin/test` or `/bin/[`. However, they're still *linked* to each other.

Comment: `[` is not an alias of test.  synonym is the word the manpage uses.  Alias has a specific meaning (in the bash manpage, read the section `ALIASES`)

Comment: Okay. I'll change that. I was simply looking for a word that would explain how the two are linked.

Answer (score 5):

They are not switches for the [`if`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/if) statement, but for the [`test`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) command (`[` is a synonym for the `test` builtin). See `help test` in Bash for a complete list.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually not `if` that's providing those — it's `[`, better known by the name of `test`. `help test` should give you a list of all options it can take. You could also look at [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), if you care.

Comment: -1: test is both a command `/bin/test` and a bash builtin.  `man test` gives you the doc for the command, but `[` is a synonym for the builtin.  As an example of divergent behavior, on OSX the bash builtin supports the `-N` test but the `/bin/test` does not