# Convert into lower case json keys using bash NOT JQ

Tags: json, bash, dictionary

I´ve a json which is a list of dictionaries with the next syntax:

```
 [ 
     {
    "Date_and_Time": "Dec 29, 2017 15:35:37",
    "Componente": "Bar",
    "IP_Origen": "175.11.13.6",
    "IP_Destino": "81.18.119.864",
    "Country": "Brazil",
    "Age": "3"

},

{

    "Date_and_Time": "Dec 31, 2017 17:35:37",
    "Componente": "Foo",
    "IP_Origen": "176.11.13.6",
    "IP_Destino": "80.18.119.864",
    "Country": "France",
     'Id': '123456',
     'Car': 'Ferrari'

},
{
  "Date_and_Time": "Dec 31, 2017 17:35:37",
    "Age": "1",
    "Country": "France",
     'Id': '123456',
     'Car': 'Ferrari'
},
{
    "Date_and_Time": "Mar 31, 2018 14:35:37",
    "Componente": "Foo",
    "Country": "Germany",
     'Id': '2468',
     'Genre': 'Male'

}
]
```

The json is really big and each dictionary have different amount of key/values fields. And what I want to do is to rewrite each character of the KEYS into lower case. Expected input:

```
[ 
     {
    "date_and_time": "Dec 29, 2017 15:35:37",
    "componente": "Bar",
    "ip_origen": "175.11.13.6",
    "ip_destino": "81.18.119.864",
    "country": "Brazil",
     .
     .
     .
```

Comment: only keys wrapped in double quotes? or do you also want to apply the 'lower()' logic to keys wrapped in single quotes? (eg, `'Id': '2468',` ==> `'id': '2468'`); what (code) have you tried so far?

Comment: Both of them. What I have thought is to implement a sed command changing every character into lower case but it's not efficient at all and it will change also the values (i only want to change keys)

Comment: Could you explain a little bit? @oguzismail

Comment: I'm not looking for a JQ solution, I would like to implement in bash

Comment: Use a JSON parser to parse JSON. Same advice for XML, HTML, CSV, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk 'NF>1{$1=tolower($1)} 1' FS=: OFS=: file
```

```
perl -pe 's/.*?:/\L$&/' file
```

GNU sed:

```
sed 's/[^:]*:/\L&/' file
```

Convert to lower case everything before the `:` character on each line. For this to work correctly, each key/val pair must occupy a single line, and keys must not contain the `:` character. In awk it can be done by splitting at `:` so that the first field may be converted. In perl the substitution operator is used to replace everything up to the first `:` with itself lowercased by the `\L` escape (info in `man 1 perlop`, [perldoc.perl.org](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)). GNU sed offers a perl-like `\L` sequence (only usable in the replacement part of `s///` in sed).

Comment: Could you explain?

Answer (score 3):

Despite my comment to your question, with bash:

```sh
# strings assigned to the "key" variable will be lower-cased
declare -l key

while IFS=: read -r key value; do
  [[ -z $value ]] && echo "$key" || echo "$key:$value"
done < file.json
```

outputs

```
 [
     {
    "date_and_time": "Dec 29, 2017 15:35:37",
    "componente": "Bar",
    "ip_origen": "175.11.13.6",
...
```

Instead of laboriously explaining each line, I'll provide some links to documentation for self-learning:

- the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) here on stackoverflow
- the [`declare` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare)
- bash FAQ #001: [How can I read a file line-by-line?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
- [List of 'if' switches anywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074542/list-of-if-switches-anywhere)
- `&&` and `||` documented at [Lists of Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) in the manual

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: Is there any particular thing you need clarity about? Or the whole answer?

Comment: The whole answer if possible

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne '@F = split /:/, $_, 2; $F[0] = lc $F[0]; print join ":", @F;' in.json > out.json
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`@F = split /:/, $_, 2;` : Split the input string `$_` into array `@F` with a max of 2 elements.

Comment: That's great but when I have the time with ':' syntax it's modified

Comment: Amazing and one last thing, it puts into my json ':' each time it´s encountering the next syntax '[' ']' '{' '}'. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: @Kiko Fixed that too, please see updated answer.